# spring boot autoconfiguration based on env variables

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, properties

In my understanding in a spring-boot application when having spring-boot-starter-data-jpa on your classpath and also **mysql-connector**
**spring-boot** will still try to use in memory h2 (as per default), if no db related properties are defined.

But if you have properties like the following:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

It will use mysql database.

My question is:
what happens if you have those properties only declared as environmental variables ?
Is this behaviour still valid ?

thanks!

Comment: Yes, environment variable placeholders may be used in properties file. See http://dolszewski.com/spring/spring-boot-application-properties-file/#properties-by-environment

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the following dependencies together: "web", "mysql", "jpa". A simple run without any configuration shows the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

And if you use the environment route instead of "application.properties" as long as you set them correctly it should act the same as a fully configured "application.properties" file.

Comment: oh yeah in my app I have h2 as well that's why it's picked up by default I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying it out !